# custom map function standard ml

Tags: types, dictionary, sml

I want to make a custom map function that does the same thing as the predefined map function in sml, I wrote the following code:

```
fun mymap f = fn L => foldr f [] L;
```

Which is bascially a function f, that can then take a list and apply the function f to the list, since map function takes a list and function and return the another list, now what I'm getting is :

```
val mymap = fn : ('a * 'b list -> 'b list) -> 'a list -> 'b list
```

but the predefined map function has the following output:

```
val it = fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
```

what is the problem that I made here?
Thanks

NOTE: I must use foldr or foldl function and use currying

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem? Well, as you can see, the problem is that the first argument to your function (`f`) has the wrong type to be used as the first argument to `foldr`. You must first understand what kind of function is required as the first argument for `foldr`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you must understand, that for each element of the list you apply foldr on, it takes an element of that list, the previous result (or the start-value) and gives both to the function wich is the first parameter of foldr.

That means, that in the code you wrote, f takes two parameters. So f takes a value of the list (`'a`) and a list (`'b list`), and that gives us the type:

```
'a * 'b list -> 'b list
```

But in the map function, you want f to be applied to each list element, so you need to make foldr's first argument an abstraction, wich applies f to the list elements, and adds the result to the output list.